# Google Colab Kernel paradigma: installation of R packages had non-zero exit status

Tags: r, google-colaboratory, install.packages

I try to use R in Google Colab using the notebook in: (https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#create=true&language=r).
But I have some problems when I try to:

```
install.packages(c("rgdal","maptools","raster","dplyr","randomForest","ggplot2",
"cluster","spatstat","factoextra","mlbench","caret","doParallel","tidyr","vegan",
"rgeos","e1071","multcomp","data.table","keras","googledrive"), dependencies=TRUE)
```

For several packages, I have the output `installation of package ‘xxxx’ had non-zero exit status` , for example.

This problem in a physical machine (or if the initial Kernel is Python) is normally solved with (UNIX language):

```
!sudo apt install libgdal-dev libproj-dev libgeos-dev libudunits2-dev libv8-dev libcairo2-dev libnetcdf-dev libcgal-dev
```

But is impossible to change the Kernel for Python in the same Google Colab session. Please, any ideas for solving it?